# OL interaction - mousedown

Tags: openlayers-3

I see that there is ol interaction that can be done upon click or single click or pointer move - however, is there one that can be done with mousedown/mouseup?  In short, we want the user to be able to edit a feature as long as the mouse button in clicked but saved/stopped upon mouse button release.

```
featureRotateDown = new ol.interaction.Select({
        condition: ol.events.condition.pointerdown
    });

    featureRotateUp = new ol.interaction.Select({
        condition: ol.events.condition.pointerup
    });

    map.addInteraction(featureRotateDown);
    map.addInteraction(featureRotateUp);

featureRotateDown.on('select', function(event) {
        $.each(event.selected, function (index, feature) {
            console.log(feature);
            console.log('1');
        });
    });

    featureRotateUp.on('select', function(event) {
        $.each(event.selected, function (index, feature) {
            console.log(feature);
            console.log('3');
        });
    });
```

In other words, imagine a marker placed on a map that is an arrow.  I want to ability to rotate it around as much as I want while the cursor is on the marker and the mouse button is pressed down.

Comment: Take a look at ol.interaction.Pointer and its handleDownEvent and handleUpEvent functions. To get the feature at the mouse down, you'll have use forEachFeatureAtPixel method.

Answer (score 1):

Try `pointerdown` and `pointerup`:

```
map.on('pointerdown', function (event) {
  // doStuff...
  // ALTERNATIVE 1: get a feature at click position (with very small tolerance)
  map.forEachFeatureAtPixel(event.pixel, function(feature, layer){
    // doStuff with your feature at click position
  });

  // ALTERNATIVE 2: get the closest feature
  closestFeature = yourVectorSource.getClosestFeatureToCoordinate(event.coordinate);
})

map.on('pointerup', function (event) {
  // doStuff...
})
```

In the functions you can access the features using `forEachFeatureAtPixel`or `getClosestFeatureToCoordinate`. 
Also see this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lars_fiddle/vny2xycn/2/)

Comment: I tried it.  The pointer up is working fine but the pointer down fails.

Comment: I need it to work with the individual features in the vector layer, not on the general map overall.  See the code I posted.

Comment: You can use `forEachFeatureAtPixel` for that.

Comment: This seems to mostly work.  My issue is that if a person does not click exactly on the arrow head, the function does not fire.  How do we work around that issue?  So that anywhere they click on the arrow, the function fires?

Comment: Inside your `map.on` function you can also use `getClosestFeatureToCoordinate` on your `ol.source vector` to select a feature to increase the tolerance. (http://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/ol.source.Vector.html#getClosestFeatureToCoordinate)

Comment: I've tried different combinations using `getClosestFeatureToCoordinate` but it keeps giving me undefined when I console log it. This is the only other place in the code that has ol.source.vector `var featureOverlay = new ol.layer.Vector({ source: new ol.source.Vector({features: features}) });`

Comment: You should post a Fiddle with your specific problem. In general the proposed solution works as you can see in my provided JSFiddle.